# cakephp create custompasswordhasher internal server error

Tags: php, cakephp-2.5, password-hash

I want to create the custompasswordhasher for my cakephp project. the cakephp version is 2.5. I have follow the cakephp cook book and create the following custom class in directory Controller/Auth/CustomPasswordHasher.php

```
App::uses('AbstractPasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class CustomPasswordHasher extends AbstractPasswordHasher {
    public function hash($password) {
        $hasher =  md5(Configure::read('Security.salt') . $password . Configure::read('Security.cipherSeed'));
        return $hasher;
    }

    public function check($password, $hashedPassword) {
        //debug('PHPassHasher'); die('Using custom hasher'); //<--THIS NEVER HAPPENS!
        $password =   md5(Configure::read('Security.salt') . $password . Configure::read('Security.cipherSeed'));
        echo $password."==".$hashedPassword;exit;
        return password_verify($password, $hashedPassword);
    }
}
```

and here is my login function in the controller

```
public function admin_login() {
    if ($this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Username or password is incorrect', 'error');
        }
    }
}
```

and in appController.php I config function

```
    public function beforeFilter() {

        if ($this->request->prefix == 'admin') {
            $this->layout = 'admin';
            AuthComponent::$sessionKey = 'Auth.User';
            $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'administrators', 'action' => 'login');
            $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'administrators', 'action' => 'dashboard');
            $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'administrators', 'action' => 'login');
            $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
                'all' => array(
                    'scope' => array(
                        'User.is_active' => 1
                    )
                ),
                'Form' => array(
                    'userModel' => 'User',
                    'passwordHasher' => array(
                        'className' => 'Auth/CustomPasswordHasher'
                    )
                )
            );
            $this->Auth->allow('login');
        } else {
            /* do another stuff for user authentication */
        }
    }
```

And here is my login form.

```
<div class="login-box">
    <div class="login-logo">Admin Login</div>
    <div class="login-box-body">
        <p class="login-box-msg">Sign in to start your session</p>
        <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
        <?php  echo $this->Form->create(); ?>
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <?php
                    echo $this->Form->input('User.username',
                        array(
                            'label'         => false,
                            'class'         => 'form-control',
                            'placeholder'   => 'Username',
                            'autocomplete'  => 'off',
                            'autofocus'     => true,
                            'value'         => @$username 
                        )
                    );
                ?>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <?php
                    echo $this->Form->input('User.password',
                        array(
                            'type'          => 'password',
                            'label'         => false,
                            'class'         => 'form-control',
                            'placeholder'   => 'Password',
                            'value'         => @$password
                        )
                    );
                ?>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-8">    
                    <div class="checkbox icheck ">
                        <label> 
                        <input type="checkbox" name="data[Admin][remember_me]"> Remember Me </label>
                    </div>                        
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
        <a href="#forgotpassword" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#forgot_password_modal1">I forgot my password</a><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

how every when submit form. I got the stack trace

[image]

So everyone can you help me with this?

Comment: Well, what is the actual error message for line 138 in passwordHasher?

Comment: well I saw the cause now. because I call wrong className in my controller . it should be "Custom" not "CustompasswordHasher". Cake will automatic add that.

Answer (score 0):

I call wrong className in my controller . it should be "Custom" not "CustompasswordHasher". Cake will automatic add that.